# JPA SELECT NEW Objeto pasando subqueries como parámetros

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Necesito ejecutar una query JPQL como esta:

```
SELECT new paquete.ClaseA(a.id, a.fecha, 
    (SELECT COUNT(b1) FROM AquellaTabla b1 
        WHERE b1.claseA.id = a.id AND 
              b1.estado = 'UNO'), 
    (SELECT COUNT(b2) FROM AquellaTabla b2 
        WHERE b2.claseA.id = a.id AND 
              b2.estado IN ('DOS', 'SIETE')), 
    a.importe) 
    FROM EstaTabla a
        WHERE a.color = 'BLANCO'
```

Pero al ejecutarla me salta una excepción:

> ```
> Caused by: (...) org.apache.openjpa.persistence.NonUniqueResultException:
> La consulta sobre el tipo candidato "class paquete.AquellaTabla" con el filtro 
> "SELECT new paquete.ClaseA(a.id, a.fecha, 
> (SELECT COUNT(b1) FROM AquellaTabla b1 WHERE b1.claseA.id = a.id AND b1.estado = 'UNO'), 
> (SELECT COUNT(b2) FROM AquellaTabla b2 WHERE b2.claseA.id = a.id AND b2.estado IN ('DOS', 'SIETE')), 
> a.importe)
>  FROM EstaTabla a 
> WHERE a.color = 'BLANCO'" 
> se ha configurado para tener un resultado único, pero más de una instancia coincidía con la consulta.
> ```

He probado la consulta en SQL y funciona correctamente, ¿Tenéis alguna solución para este error?

Answer (score 1):

En JPQL, no puedes pasarle valores a pelo, debes crearte una Lista y dentro de la lista insertar los valores, de esa forma puedes tener varios valores.

Para ello, debes crearte una lista (en la solución, la lista se crea en la misma clase: AquellaTabla) y luego usarla.

Total, que deberías tener:

```
SELECT COUNT(b2) FROM AquellaTabla b2 
        WHERE b2.claseA.id = a.id AND 
              b2.estado IN b2.miListaDeValores
```

Si son poco valores, podrías usar el operador OR, tal que:

```
SELECT COUNT(b2) FROM AquellaTabla b2 
        WHERE b2.claseA.id = a.id AND 
              b2.estado = 'DOS' OR b2.estado ='SIETE'
```

Espero que te ayude =D.

Si no te funciona, prueba a ponerlo entre paréntesis, tal que:

```
SELECT COUNT(b2) FROM AquellaTabla b2 
            WHERE b2.claseA.id = a.id AND 
                  b2.estado IN (b2.miListaDeValores)
```

fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378824/adding-in-clause-list-to-a-jpa-query

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y sigue dando el mismo resultado; debe ser por otro motivo.

Comment: Seguro que te funciona usar esto: **b1.claseA.id** y **b2.claseA.id**, es lo único que podría fallar, por lo demás está correcto.